# xdebug_get_code_coverage() returns an empty array

Tags: php, xdebug

I have the following at the beginning of a script:

```
if ($jsonFile = $_REQUEST['saveCoverageJson']??'')
{
    xdebug_start_code_coverage();
    register_shutdown_function(function() use ($jsonFile)
    {
        // wrapped to make pretty sure it's the very last thing executed
        register_shutdown_function(function() use ($jsonFile)
        {
            xdebug_stop_code_coverage();
            $dir = __DIR__.'/../misc/coverage-reports';
            $coverageData = xdebug_get_code_coverage();
            var_dump($coverageData);
            file_put_contents(
                $dir."/$jsonFile.json",
                json_encode($coverageData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
            );
        });
    });
}
```

But xdebug_get_code_coverage() is returning an empty array. What's going wrong? I have `xdebug.mode` set to `coverage`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because I called `xdebug_stop_code_coverage()`. According to [the documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_set_filter) it destroys the information collected!